# Ordinal vs Regular Factors in R - is there a difference in modeling

Tags: r, categorical-data, random-forest, boosting

Can someone explain to me or show me an example of the difference between an ordinal variable and a regular categorical variable in R and how the outcome differs?  Is there even a difference at all?

Does the impact vary or matter at all across difference types of models?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

Ordinal factors are split just like continuous variables. That is, adjacency in values is preserved. An ordered factor of say, A < B < C < D can only be split in three distinct ways: (A, BCD); (AB, CD); (ABC, D).

Contrast this with a nominal factor which considers all possible subsets of the factor. This means A and D can be grouped together as nominal factors, while they cannot as ordinal.

This is the only difference in the way decision trees treat such factors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are including them as predictors in a regression model then they will be treated differently but this depends on what contrasts you have specified for them. By default factors use treatment contrasts and ordinal factors use polynomial contrasts. I suggest you make up a test dataset and declare one of the predictors (one with several levels, not just two) as a factor, run your model, and then change it to ordered and re-run the same model. That should give you a better picture than any invented example I can provide.

Comment: thank you.  i imagine this is a very common error that most people make - that they don't order these facotrs correctly?

Comment: If you are using ordinary factors you can change the order in which R prints the levels if that helps.